# Adding Layout in QT on QMain WIndow using a code

Tags: c++, qt

I need some help I need to set a layout for my application but i don't know how to set layout on QmainWindow..

here is a part of my code for the window.cpp:

```
window::window(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{


    createFilesTable();

    queryopen();
    exitButton = createButton("E&xit",SLOT(programout()));
    insertButton = createButton("&Add", SLOT(insert()));
    editButton = createButton("&Edit", SLOT(edit()));
    clearButton = createButton("&Clear", SLOT(clear()));
    selectButton = createButton("&Select", SLOT(select()));

    QHBoxLayout *buttonsLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    buttonsLayout->addStretch();
    buttonsLayout->addWidget(selectButton);
    buttonsLayout->addWidget(insertButton);
    buttonsLayout->addWidget(editButton);
    buttonsLayout->addWidget(clearButton);
    buttonsLayout->addWidget(exitButton);

    txtid   = new QLineEdit;
    txtname = new QLineEdit;
    txtdesc = new QLineEdit;
    label1 = new QLabel("ID:");
    label2 = new QLabel("Name:");
    label3 = new QLabel("Description:");

    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(label1,1,0,1,1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(txtid,1,1,1,2);
    mainLayout->addWidget(label2,2,0,1,1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(txtname,2,1,1,3);
    mainLayout->addWidget(label3,3,0,1,1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(txtdesc,3,1,1,3);
    mainLayout->addLayout(buttonsLayout,4,1,1,3);
    mainLayout->addWidget(filesTable,6,0,6,5);
    setLayout(mainLayout);


    setWindowTitle("Database Connection");
    resize(450,300);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a `QMainWindow`, you use [setCentralWidget(QWidget*)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget), unlike all other `QWidget` subclasses.

The reason is that `QMainWindow` already has its own layout, which includes places for menu bar, status bar, dock windows, etc. So you create another `QWidget` and set **its** layout to the layout you want, then make that `QWidget` the central widget of the `QMainWindow`.

(*This inconsistency has gotten me a few times ... but it makes sense once you understand what is going on.*)